# ANTLR C# target running faster in profile mode

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have a complex tool using ANTLR. It is written in C#.
My tool takes more than 3 minutes to process a file.
Unless I set the profiling option to true:

`parser.Profile = true;`

Now, the file processes in less than one second.

I can't understand how enabling profiling makes anything faster.
While I can leave the profiling active, it does not make sense.
Any hint?

**Further information:**

I am using the parser in multiple files. A new instance of the lexer and parser are created for each file. Somehow, if I parse only the file that is giving a timeout, it parses fast. If I parse another one before (already identified which), I get that 3 minutes time.

I tried to get into the Instance and clear the DFA in the parser and lexer, without luck.

Nevertheless, I suppose this means that ANTLR is caching some information that is not helping the second file parse. Probably because the grammar is ambiguous (I know it is, working on that). But it also means that enabling profiling, that cache is cleaned for each instance.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: I would not turn on profiling just to make the parser work faster. A profiling ATN interpreter should not run faster than the usual parsing ATN interpreter because it must take the extra time accumulate the statistics for the parse. In fact, the profiling ATN interpreter just wraps the usual ATN interp. Please provide a minimal example for us to reproduce and debug.

Comment: Make sure you are not measuring a cold and a hot ANTLR4 runtime between test runs. Run all tests with exactly the same input and settings at least 2 times to measure performance. The second run is usually much faster.

Comment: @kaby76 I would love that, too, but not easy. I suppose it won't happen in a standard small sample. Mostly sure I am doing something wrong, but no idea where, yet.

Comment: @MikeLischke Curiously, working fast in your plugin for Rider, so no idea why running so slowly in the production code without the profiling flag.

Comment: Does your grammar contain any actions? (Run [find-actions.sh](https://github.com/kaby76/g4-scripts/blob/main/find-actions.sh) or just look for `{ .... }` blocks in lexer or parser rules on the right hand side.) If so, the parse using the Antlr4 extension for Rider doesn't execute actions; it can't "work".

Comment: @kaby76 Yeah, I have predicates. I tried to remove it without any luck. As you pointed out, profiling just adds a wrapper, so I am still wondering what is going on with my code. My only idea was if I was taking advantage of profiling information in a predicate, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Are the semantic predicates correctly placed in the grammar? Semantic predicates must be placed at the beginning of an alt. For example, `s: {...}? foo bar | { ... }? me too | okay ;` have all the semantic predicates in the correct place for shunting an alt. The predicate in `gee: whiz [ ...}?;` is not. This has some implications on error recovery.

Comment: (Actually, for lexers, the semantic predicate should not be at the beginning of an alt because that will result in a performance issue.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256022/discussion-between-alberto-and-kaby76).